# C code is giving zero value every time. What can I correct?

Tags: c

I am starter in the C.I wrote a simple code which are calculating how many digits are the entered Number and sum of entered number’s digits.Code calculating digit count right but sum of digits being given as ‘0’ every time.Could you say where is my error?thanks.

```
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

int ndigit(int val) {
    if (val == 0)
        return 0;
    int digit_count = 1;
    while ((val = getchar() != '\n')) {
        digit_count++;
        val /= 10;
    }
    return digit_count;

}


  int sumdigit(int number) {
    int result = 0;
    while ((number = getchar()) != '\n'){
            result += number - '0';


    }

    return result;


}


int main()
{
    int a;

    printf("Bir tam sayi giriniz: \n");

    a = getchar();

    printf("Bu sayinin basamak sayisi =%d", ndigit(a));
    printf("Bu sayinin basamak degeri toplami= %d", sumdigit(a));
}

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

Comment: That must be `while ((val = getchar()) != '\n')` (wrong place of closing brace)

Comment: If you are entering the number as input only once and then pressing return or enter multiple times, the sum of the digits is shown as zero because the first function consumes the input digits, and there are none left for the second function to consume. The input data is not automatically repeated for the second function. Your program must either both count and sum as each digit is read or it must remember all of the input digits.

Answer (score 0):

You code has 3 `getchar()` that are independent. Just use one `getchar`, either in `main`, or `ndigit` or `sumdigit`.

I propose, you should get the number in `main` function using `scanf` instead of `getchar()`, then pass the number as the argument to the other functions (`ndigit` and `sumdigit`). Because `getchar` reads character by character, and it does not guarantee the character is a digit or not.

The main function becomes:

```
int main () {
   int num;
   printf("enter the number: ");
   scanf("%d", &num);

   // calling the ndigit and sumdigit function:
   printf("sum of digits = %d\n number of digits = %d\n", sumdigit(num), ndigit(num));
   return 0;
}
```

For two function `ndigit` and `sumdigit`, you can change to:

1. `ndigit` function:

```
int ndigit(int number) {
   number = abs(number); // calculate abs if the number is negative
   if(number == 0)
      return 1;
   int count = 0;
   do {
        count++;
        num /= 10;
    } while(num != 0);
    return count;
}
```

2. `sumdigit` function:

```
int sumdigit(int number) {
   number = abs(number); // calculate abs if the number is negative
   int sum = 0, temp = 0;
   while (number != 0) {
      temp    = number % 10;
      sum    += temp;
      number /= 10;
   }
   return sum;
}
```

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ndigit(int number) {
   number = abs(number); // calculate abs if the number is negative
   if(number == 0)
      return 1;
   int count = 0;
   do {
        count++;
        number /= 10;
    } while(number != 0);
    return count;
}

int sumdigit(int number) {
   number = abs(number); // calculate abs if the number is negative
   int sum = 0, temp = 0;
   while (number != 0) {
      temp    = number % 10;
      sum    += temp;
      number /= 10;
   }
   return sum;
}

int main () {
   int num;
   printf("enter the number: ");
   scanf("%d", &num);

   // calling the ndigit and sumdigit function:
   printf("sum of digits = %d\nnumber of digits = %d\n", sumdigit(num), ndigit(num));
   return 0;
}
```

The output of test:

```
enter the number: 222333                                                                                                
sum of digits = 15                                                                                                      
number of digits = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

The program does not make sense. To enter a number you should use one function. That is the number of digits and the sum of digits must be calculated for the same number.

This condition in the while statement

```
while ((val = getchar() != '\n')) {
```

is equivalent to

```
while ( ( val = ( getchar() != '\n' ) ) ) {
```

and as a result the integer `val` gets either `1` or `0`.

As the variable `val` stores an internal representation of a character (for example its ASCII value) then this statement

```
    val /= 10;
```

also does not make sense. Also the user can enter a non-digit character.

You should either use a character array for the entered number by means of calls of the function `getchar` or use the function `scanf` to enter a value of an integer object.

If to use a character array then the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * get_number( char *number, size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    int c;

    while( i + 1 < n && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' && '0' <= c && c <= '9' )
    {
        number[i++] = c;
    }

    number[i] = '\0';

    return number;
}

size_t ndigit( const char *number ) 
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( number[n] != '\0' ) ++n;

    return n;
}

unsigned int sumdigit( const char *number )
{
    unsigned int sum = 0;

    while ( *number != '\0' )
    {
        sum += *number++ - '0';
    }

    return sum;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 50 };
    char number[N];

    printf( "Bir tam sayi giriniz: " );

    get_number( number, N );

    printf( "Bu sayinin basamak sayisi = %zu\n", ndigit( number ) );
    printf( "Bu sayinin basamak degeri toplami = %u\n", sumdigit( number ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Bir tam sayi giriniz: 123456789987654321
Bu sayinin basamak sayisi = 18
Bu sayinin basamak degeri toplami = 90
```

If to use an integer number then the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t ndigit( unsigned long long number ) 
{
    const unsigned long long Base = 10;

    size_t n = 0;

    do
    {
        ++n;    
    } while ( number /= Base );

    return n;
}

unsigned int sumdigit( unsigned long long number )
{
    const unsigned long long Base = 10;

    unsigned int sum = 0;

    do
    {
        sum += number % Base;
    } while ( number /= Base );

    return sum;
}

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned long long number = 0;

    printf( "Bir tam sayi giriniz: " );

    scanf( "%llu", &number );

    printf( "Bu sayinin basamak sayisi = %zu\n", ndigit( number ) );
    printf( "Bu sayinin basamak degeri toplami = %u\n", sumdigit( number ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look as it is shown above.

```
Bir tam sayi giriniz: 123456789987654321
Bu sayinin basamak sayisi = 18
Bu sayinin basamak degeri toplami = 90
```

Answer (score -1):

After using `scanf`, change your sumdigit while loop to:

```
while (number > 0) {
    result += number % 10;
    number /= 10;
}
```